# JSQMessagesViewController can't find heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

as my questions already says: I am currently implementing the JSQMessagesViewController component in Xamarin.iOS and everything works fine for now, but for some reason I can not find the heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath method as described at [this link](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.4/Protocols/JSQMessagesCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.html#//api/name/collectionView:layout:heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:). All the other methods are visible to me, even the one that returns the attributed text for the top cell label.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used the GetCellTopLabelAttributedText and modified it to fit my use case. In other words I central aligned the text, deleted the contentInset and changed the font. I gave up looking for the method that was missing

Answer (score 1):

Wow I did not even know that you could use this library in Xamarin apps but also I don't do anything in Xamarin but that is super cool. Well as per your question. I was not able to see that method either so maybe the documentation is off but to use:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: indexPath) ? 0 : kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault
}
```

The only difference is that it is referencing the `messageBubbleTopLabel` and not the `CellTopLabel` per say. I think that is the correct method to use.

In the screen shot provided I show how this effects the look of the messages. The first message has the size set to `kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault` and the message fallowing it has it set to `0`

[image: Screen shot of Dans JSQ implimentation]

So if that is what you are trying to achieve then this is the method for you.   if not, let me know and I will see if there is something else that we can do.

Keep up the good work.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks so much for your answer! I also could only find the method for the messageBubbleTopLabel, but the problem is that I'd like to use the cellTopLabel to display the timestamp. It has better features for this as to being centered in the screen and i can use the messageBubbletopLabel for the name as you suggested. I am just still quite confused how i cant find it haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for GetMessageBubbleTopLabelHeight !

I'm not aware of any Xamarin oriented doc for this lib, but I'll gladly give you an example usage =)

This is how i used the function :

```
public override nfloat GetMessageBubbleTopLabelHeight (MessagesCollectionView collectionView, MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewLayout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Message message = Messages [indexPath.Row];

        if (message.SenderId == Sender.UserId.ToString())
            return 0.0f;

        if (indexPath.Row - 1 >= 0) {
            Message previousMessage = Messages [indexPath.Row - 1];
            if (previousMessage.SenderId == message.SenderId)
                return 0.0f;
        }
        return 20.0f;
    }
```

Comment: If I may suggest some ways to make your answer more attractive: add a reference to documentation and example usage

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Thanks for the advice !

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer! Unfortunately this is the method used for the MessageBubbleTopLabel not CellTopLabel. I am able to override the GetMessageBubbleTopLabelAttributedText and GetMessageBubbleTopLabelHeight, both used for the MessageBubbleTopLabel (usually used for the name). I am also able to override GetCellTopLabelAttributedText, but what I am missing is the heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath which is used in order to show, or not to show the CellTopLabel (which is used for the time stamp in most applications)

Comment: @FlorensvonBuchwaldt sorry, i misread. i can't find the function you're looking for. I only have access to GetCellBottomLabelHeight. Hope you find the answer !